# keep data order for geom_bar() ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I created the following dataframe:

```
    condition <- rep(c("Pretreatment", "Normal"), 4)
    value <- c( "3.6", "0.2", "5.6", "0.2", "7.4", "0.2", "8.8", "0.2")
    time<- c("5","5", "10", "10", "15","15", "20", "20")
    domedata <- data.frame(time, condition, value)
```

I want to keep the bars for time in x in order since it is telling us about time 5min, 10min, 15min, 20 min. ggplot is ploting my 5min at the end. I am doing this:

```
    ggplot(domedata, aes(fct_infreq(time), fill=condition, x=time, y=value)) +
           geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Convert time to a numeric or try with `forcats::fct_inorder`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are passing to `x` aesthetics, so the last will overwrite the first.
Below i removed the first argument to aesthetics which is redundant, the i used the `fct_inorder`, as @stefan also commented

```
condition <- rep(c("Pretreatment", "Normal"), 4)
value <- c( "3.6", "0.2", "5.6", "0.2", "7.4", "0.2", "8.8", "0.2")
time <- c("5","5", "10", "10", "15","15", "20", "20")
domedata <- data.frame(time, condition, value)

ggplot(domedata, aes(fill=condition, x=fct_inorder(time), y=value)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
```

But note that as your values are strings, so the scale of the y-axis is kinda weird,  i would suggest that you convert both value and time to the numeric data type, by removing the quotes, like this

```
library(tidyverse)

condition <- rep(c("Pretreatment", "Normal"), 4)
value <- c(3.6, 0.2, 5.6, 0.2, 7.4, 0.2, 8.8, 0.2)
time <- c(5,5, 10, 10, 15,15, 20, 20)
domedata <- data.frame(time, condition, value)

ggplot(domedata, aes(fill=condition, x=time, y=value)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity")
```

that way the plot will be less misleading.